# add a custom validator that compares 2 dates in reactive form with addControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator

I’m going to create a validator that compares 2 dates in a reactive form like this (it's in WIP). The 'dateFrom' FormControl value must be < to the 'dateTo' FormControl value:

```
// Validator WIP
export function compareTwoDatesValidator() {
  return (form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let errors: ValidationErrors | null;

    if (form.get('dateTo')?.value > form.get('dateFrom')?.value) {
      form.get('dateTo')?.setErrors({ IsRequired: true });
      return errors = {
        ['test']: true
      };
    } else {
      return errors = null;
    }
  };
}
```

I have to integrate my validator in a form that has addControl() on the dates to compare like this in the model. This model is a child class:

```
  public override ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();
this.form.addControl('globalSearch', new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.globalSearch)
    this.form.addControl('dateFrom', new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.dateFrom));
    this.form.addControl('dateTo', new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.dateTo));
  }
```

Here's the form in the parent abstract class where the reactive form is created:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
    {
      codeApporteur: new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.codeApporteur, [
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ]),
      codeVendeur: new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.codeVendeur, [
        Validators.maxLength(2)
      ])
    },
    { validators: mandatoryInputsValidator('codeApporteur', 'codeVendeur') }
  );
```

My question is : how can I use my interceptor in child class on date FormControls ?
Thanks for help

Comment: You can create formGroup and add validator inside that group something like this? this.form.addControl('date', new FormGroup({
from:new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.dateFrom),
from:new FormControl(this.dataSearch?.dateTo)
}, { validators: compareTwoDatesValidator() }));

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try it